# ios scrolling like so

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm in the code design phase of a project and I am not sure if this style of scrolling custom items is available without a bit of custom code, so I'm running it by SOF to find out.

```
-----------------------------
|A            B            C|
|--+    +-----------+    +--|
|  |    |           |    |  |
|  |    |           |    |  |
|  |    |           |    |  |
|  |    |           |    |  |
|  |    |           |    |  |
|--+    +-----------+    +--|
|                           |
-----------------------------
```

Per my developer graphics, you can invision a `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled`. My questions is, will the `UIScrollView` allow me to show the edges of neighboring items when an item has claimed the center position?

*Thanks in advance!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has popped up several times; I've never implemented this myself, but most of the answers seem to involve combining a few things:

- The scroll view frame should be set up as if you only wanted to show a single page, in the middle of the view.
- The scroll view needs to have it's `clipsToBounds` property set to `NO`, so it will show the other pages.
- No user touches will get to the scroll view if the user touches the partially exposed pages, since those are now technically outside the scroll bounds, so you have to override a method on `UIView` to hijack the normal method of routing touches to views. The scroll view should be inside or behind this custom view.

Edit: Here's [a tutorial](http://blog.proculo.de/index.php?url=archives/180-Paging-enabled-UIScrollView-With-Previews.html) that describes what you're after.

Comment: worked like a charm. I've implemented this *five* times on this project so far.